# loop does'nt take case function and return empty result

Tags: php

I will try to insert inside dropdown information but it's always empty.
Like you can see insde the code the case is not injected inside $lc_text

for ($col = 0, $n = count($column_list); $col < $n; $col++) {

```
              var_dump($column_list);
              var_dump($column_list[$col]);


              switch ($column_list[$col]) {
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_DATE_ADDED':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_date');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_PRICE':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_price');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MODEL':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_model');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_NAME':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_products');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MANUFACTURER':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_manufacturer');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_QUANTITY':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_quantity');
                break;
                case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_WEIGHT':
                  $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_weight');
                break;
              }




var_dump($lc_text);
              $new_lc_text = $OSCOM_ProductsCommon->createSortHeading($_GET['sort'], $col+1, $lc_text);
```

var_dump($new_lc_text);

```
              $new_prods_content .= '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">' . $new_lc_text . '</button>';

        }
```

Result of the different element :

```
var_dump($column_list);
array (size=7)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_NAME' => string 'module_products_search_list_name' (length=32)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MODEL' => string 'module_products_search_list_model' (length=33)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MANUFACTURER' => string 'module_products_search_list_manufacturer' (length=40)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_PRICE' => string 'module_products_search_list_price' (length=33)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_QUANTITY' => string 'module_products_search_list_quantity' (length=36)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_WEIGHT' => string 'module_products_search_list_weight' (length=34)
  'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_DATE_ADDED' => string 'module_products_search_list_date_added' (length=38)


var_dump($column_list[$col]);
 '<a href="http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/Search/Q/keywords,t/page,1/sort,1a" title="Sort productsascendinglyby" class="productListing-heading"></a>' (length=169)


var_dump($lc_text);
/home/www/test/boutique/sources/template/Default/modules/modules_products_search/pse_products_search.php:94:null


'var_dump($new_lc_text);
<a href="http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/Search/Q/keywords,t/page,1/sort,1a" title="Sort productsascendinglyby" class="productListing-heading"></a>'
```

Comment: `$lc_text` vs `$lc_text1`?

Comment: see error and change in consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check **key** of your array, not it's value:

```
foreach ($column_list as $k => $v) {

  switch ($k) {
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_DATE_ADDED':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_date');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_PRICE':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_price');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MODEL':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_model');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_NAME':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_products');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_MANUFACTURER':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_manufacturer');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_QUANTITY':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_quantity');
    break;
    case 'MODULE_PRODUCTS_SEARCH_LIST_WEIGHT':
      $lc_text = OSCOM::getDef('table_heading_weight');
    break;
  }

  var_dump($lc_text);
  // I don't know what `$col+1` means, but I suppose it 
  // should be rewritten too, as `$col` is NOT used now
  $new_lc_text = $OSCOM_ProductsCommon->createSortHeading($_GET['sort'], $col+1, $lc_text);

  var_dump($new_lc_text);
  $new_prods_content .= '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">' . $new_lc_text . '</button>';
}
```